# Add nth-child odd and even in a div for multiple lines

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have, let's say, 10 lines of text in a post, and I want to include them in a that will add different style (like font size or color) to line one and line two, and then repeat it automatically no matter how many lines are. so line one will have the same style as line 3, 5, 7, 9 and line two will have the same style as line 4, 6, 8, 10 and so on, if the list would be bigger...

From what I see I could use something like

```
 p:nth-child(odd) 
 { 
     background:#ff0000; 
 } 

 p:nth-child(even)  
 { 
     background:#0000ff; 
 }
```

but the problem is I do not want to add a `<p>` to every line, I want to add a `<div class="something">` before the first line and close it after the line 10 `</div>`

How to make this work?

thank you

Comment: did not understand your question ? a fiddle or html code could help.

and explain clearly

Comment: This isn't possible. You can only style HTML elements, not individual lines. Even if you wrapped every line within a `div`, there's no guarantee that line wouldn't wrap onto a second line because of different screen widths (unless you used the css whitespace rule I suppose).

Comment: instead of using paragraphs for every line, I want the div to be able to 'count' the lines itself, to know automatically what style to add to the lines